# Why this Angular filter is not working

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've got a filter so I can search for a list of products. The catch is, the list o products is nested (I've got an object which is called category, which contains an object with a series of objects called subcategories, which in turn contains an object called products that contains a series of products. These are the ones I want to filter on). My code is as follows (I'm using Jade btw):

```
accordion-group(ng-repeat="category in categories", is-open="category.active")
    ...
    tab(ng-repeat="subcat in category.subcategories", active="subcat.active")
    ...
        input(type="text", ng-model="searchText")
        tr(ng-repeat="prod in subcat.products|filter:searchText")
        ...
```

I've used Angular's filter similarly before and it worked fine (not nested within ng-repeats though) and I can't see what I'm missing.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Adding `subcat.products` structure

```
"46ad-97d9-bd3cfe" : {
        "name" : "Meat",
        "id" : "46ad-97d9-bd3cfe",
        "editing" : false,
        "active" : true,
        "products" : {
            "45ed-a686-e45e52" : {
                "name" : "Sirloin Steak",
                "price" : 10,
                "sku" : "MT001",
                "id" : "45ed-a686-e45e52",
                "editing" : false
            },
            ...
        }
    },
```

Many thanks

Comment: Can you show your `subcat.products` structure?

Comment: What markup is created? `, active="subcat.active")` looks like it will create a new attribute.

Comment: @Oledje - I've just added the structure.

Comment: @DavinTryon - `active="subcat.active"` is a function that will fire once the tab becomes active. I'm using AngularBootstrap UI.